# Why has the numpy random.choice() function been discontinued?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I've been working with numpy and needed the random.choice() function. Sadly, in version 2.0 it's not in the random or the random.mtrand.RandomState modules. Has it been excluded for a particular reason? There's nothing in the discussion or documentation about it!

For info, I'm running Numpy 2.0 on python 2.7 on mac os. All installed from the standard installers provided on the sites.

Thanks!

Comment: My first guess is that it isn't discontinued but that you haven't installed numpy correctly. Docs say new for numpy 1.7.0, do you have at least that version installed?

Comment: I've got version 2.0 installed, so I checked that, sorry for not mentioning on the original question! Also, from what I've found in the doc, random.choice doesn't allow you to specify the weights, and choosing a random element uniformly is pretty straightforward. It's pretty straightforward with weights as well, just thought it might be interesting to have it in numpy. I implemented it myself then: http://pastebin.com/wpQ08xqV

Comment: There is no such thing as numpy 2.0 at this time. You have installed some unknown revision of the development sources that happens to list itself as 2.0. You probably got a revision before `choice()` was added.

Comment: Wow, that's pretty weird. I really don't remember exactly where I installed from, but I'll be sure to try to downgrade to the supported version! I was pretty sure I was on standard numpy! Noob of me I guess!

Comment: I am also feeling confused about it, it seems the numpy.random.choice function is gone...

Comment: Pretty sure you're running a wrong version of numpy, just as me. Try importing numpy and then checking numpy.__version__, to see which version you're running. 1.7 should work. I had accidentally installed 2.0, probably through macports. Just make sure you're in the right version and it should work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`random.choice` is as far as I can tell part of python itself, not of numpy. Did you `import random`?

Update: numpy 1.7 added a new function, `numpy.random.choice`. Obviously, you need numpy 1.7 for it.

Update2: it seems that in **unreleased** numpy 2.0, this was temporarily called `numpy.random.sample`. It has been renamed back. Which is why when using *unreleased* versions, you really should have a look at the API (`pydoc numpy.random`) and changelogs.

Comment: Python and numpy both have a random.choice() function.

Comment: random.choice() chooses uniformly, and I can't find numpy.random.choice neither numpy.random.mtrand.RandomState.choice() in my numpy 2.0 installation.

Comment: Then maybe you should stick to the latest release. 2.0 is not yet complete. Anyway, you could try `numpy.random.sample` which apparently was renamed back to `numpy.random.choice` sometime in december.

Comment: `random.sample` draws from random floats in the half-open interval [0.0, 1.0]. `numpy.random.choice` randomly draws elements from a numpy array. They're different things entirely.

Comment: @NickCrawford `random.sample` is different from `numpy.random.sample`.. The only difference that I see between `random.sample` and `numpy.random.choice` is that the latter returns a numpy array rather than a normal python array. Plus the arguments of `numpy.random.choice` that allow you to sample with replacement and with some weights to individual elements.